# How to design tables with a higher level of nesting?

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm making an online movie-database as a project for school with C#. At this moment i'm working on the database model. In my movie database you can comment on news-articles, movies and on a comment itself. As you can see in the image-link below, i have designed a comment table, which can have an Article_ID or Movie_ID or none of them if it is a comment on a comment. Is this a good practice?

http://s17.postimg.org/dg6wnp6jz/comment_table.png

My intuition says no. Is it not better to create more tables? One for movie-comments, one for the news-comments and one for the comments on comments? Or is it better to make junction tables for it?

What is a good practice to deal with this higher level of nesting? [think of a comment on a comment, which also has a comment on itself]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clould use a model tree structure with parent references, for example:

**movie-posts**

```
id          | movie_id | post_text            | date_of_post | post_author
-----------   --------   --------------------   ------------   -----------
post_movie1 | movie1   | the post about movie | today        | one author
```

**movie-posts-comments**

```
id    | movie_post_id | parent_comment_id | comment_text                       | datetime_of_comment | commenter
-----  --------------- | ----------------  ----------------------------------- | ------------------- | ----------------
comm1 | post_movie1    | null             | first comment about movie1         | today 10:10:01      | user one
comm2 | post_movie1    | null             | second comment about movie1        | today 10:50:01      | user two
comm3 | post_movie1    | comm2            | first commet about comm2 of movie1 | today 11:10:10      | user one   
comm4 | post_movie1    | null             | another comment about movie1       | today 12:15:00      | other user
comm5 | post_movie1    | comm2            | second comment about comm2 movie1  | today 16:50:01      | user two
```

You will have all commets in a same table. The new and old comments can be identified easily by datetime, and de relation between comments can be identified by parent relation field

this structure is a good alternative to a nested model structure; you will have less reading effort (a single table - single query ) and your write transaction will be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriateness of a solution would probably depend on the development framework.

If this was Ruby on Rails, I'd say that what you have there is a polymorphic relationship, in which the comment table would have columns "commentable_type" and "commentable_id". The commentable_type would contain the name of the associated table (or model, in Rails terminology) such as "Movie", "Article", "Comment", etc, and the commentable_id would contain its primary key.

This generally would mean that you could not use a database foreign key constraint, and would have to rely on application-enforced integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a Reply table that references the Comment table